# Как сохранить появившейся блок при click js

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно что-бы после данной функции (при нажатии `.fa-music`), блок у которого добавился класс `visib` не исчезал после обновления страницы, а исчез только после того как нажать обратно `.fa-music`

```
$(".fa-music").click(function(){
  $(".jp-audio").toggleClass("visib");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположим, что в первоначальном виде страницы у `.jp-audio` нет класса `visib`. Тогда, при готовности страницы добавим проверку на наличие нашего значения в хранилище текущей сессии `sessionStorage` (для случая перезагрузки страницы):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Получение данных из sessionStorage
  var data = sessionStorage.getItem('visib');
  // если значение есть - тогда класс у элемента должен быть
  if (data) {
    $(".jp-audio").addClass("visib"); // добавим класс
  }
}
```

Данный подход гарантирует нам, что после перезагрузки страницы данные в текущей сессии останутся и мы сможем привязать класс к нужному элементу. Соответственно, в самом обработчике клика нам необходимо будет либо добавлять значение в сессию, либо удалять.

```
$(".fa-music").click(function(){
  // если класс был (значит далее он будет удален)
  if ($(".jp-audio").hasClass("visib")) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('visib'); // удалим из хранилища
  } else {
    // если класса "visib" у ".jp-audio" не было
    sessionStorage.setItem('visib', true); // добавим в хранилище
  }

  $(".jp-audio").toggleClass("visib"); // добавим/удалим класс "visib"
});
```

> Свойство [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) позволяет получить доступ к объекту
>   Storage текущей сессии. Данные в `sessionStorage` очищаются в момент
>   окончания сессии текущий страницы. Сессия страницы остается активной
>   все время пока окно браузера открыто и сохраняется между
>   перезагрузками страниц. Открытие той же страницы в новом окне браузера
>   или новой вкладке приводит к созданию новой сессии страницы.

Также, ссылки, которые будут полезны:

- [Интерфейс `Storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Storage)
- [`Window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)
- [`Window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
- [`.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)
- [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)
- [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)
- [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: Спасибо Большое